# Generics Question ordering

Tags: c#, .net, generics

In an interview they told me

Write the code in the brackets to order the list.   They said order but you dont know if the type is going to be `int` or `decimal`.

They also told me not to use framework methods like `.sort`

So I have no idea how would I do it?  I need to be ready for the next time somebody asks me this.

Possible Inputs: 7,3,8,6,1
Or:   6.9, 4.5, 2.3,  6.1, 9.9

```
namespace InterViewPreparation1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<int> list= new List<int>();
            list.Add(int.Parse(i1.Text));
            list.Add(int.Parse(i2.Text));
            list.Add(int.Parse(i3.Text));
            list.Add(int.Parse(i4.Text));
            list.Add(int.Parse(i5.Text));
            Sort(list);
        }


        private void Sort<T>(List<T> list)
        {
            bool madeChanges;
            int itemCount = list.Count;
            do
            {
                madeChanges = false;
                itemCount--;
                for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
                {
                    int result = Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(list[i], list[i + 1]);

                    if (result > 0)
                    {
                        Swap(list, i, i + 1);
                        madeChanges = true;
                    }
                }
            } while (madeChanges);            
        }


        public  List<T> Swap<T>(this List<T> list,
                int firstIndex,
                int secondIndex)
        {
            T temp = list[firstIndex];
            list[firstIndex] = list[secondIndex];
            list[secondIndex] = temp;

            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Howcome there's no generic parameter on your List?

Comment: Since you're not in the interview anymore, you can use Google. What have you tried yourself?

Comment: Just use if(list[i] < list[i+1]) comparisons?

Comment: I guess the idea is that they want you to write your own sort using `IComparable<T>` to compare the elements.

Comment: @Ian you can't use operators such as `<` against `T`

Comment: @Sven Indeed thats what they wanted, I guess Marc Gravell solution below is very close to what they ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, both [Int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx) and [Double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx) implement [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) - this means that you should cast each element to an IComparable when performing your sort.  As you can't use any standard .Net sorting method you need to implement one yourself.  See [Sorting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) for some inspiration.

It would be easier if the method signature was different:

```
public void sortlist<T>(List<T> list)
    where T : IComparable
{

}
```

An example implementation of [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort):

```
for (int pass = 1; pass < list.Count; pass++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        if (list[i].CompareTo(list[i + 1]) > 0)
        {
            // Swap
            T temp = list[i];
            list[i] = list[i + 1];
            list[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively if T isn't constrained to `IComparable` then you can tweak this slightly as per Marcs suggestion by using `Comparer<T>.Default`:

```
Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(list[i], list[i + 1])
```

Comment: can you please check the edit, I have some compiler errors, I am trying to do this exercise in a simple winform. but I am having problems

Comment: @Luis Compiles fine for me, are you sure that you are declaring the type parameter T in either your class name or method body?  You should read up on [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: pls see the edit, I am very close to the solution, but I have this compiler error:  Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

Answer (score 6):

It depends how far down the line of "don't use framework methods" you go. Or should we be using logic probes against raw memory? Frankly, *not* just using `list.Sort()` is stupid (it is a bad interview question, IMO; I'd argue "no, I'm using `list.Sort()` - it exists and does the job nicely").

But! Another approach here would be to obtain:

```
var comparer = System.Collections.Generic.Comparer<T>.Default;
```

now you have a type-safe comparer that will work for any `T` with sortability. The act of calling `.Compare` lots of times to place into sequence is left as an exercise, and any text-book sorting strategy will work using `comparer.Compare(x, y)`.

Comment: can you please check the edit, I have some compiler errors, I am trying to do this exercise in a simple winform. but I am having problems

Comment: @Luis as per Justin's answer - `private void  Sort<T>(List<T> list)`

Comment: pls see the edit, I am very close to the solution, but I have this compiler error:  Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class