# How to instantiate a generic list without knowing the type

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I created a method to organize a generic list without know the type, it will sort if its int or decimal.

However the code that retrieves the values from textboxes uses List

I tried to convert it to List, but it doesnt work.
I want this code to work if they type integers or decimals or strings in the textboxes.

This was part of an interview question where they asked not to use the sort method, and that the input should receive for example INTS or DECIMALS

```
private void btnSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            list.Add(int.Parse(i1.Text));
            list.Add(int.Parse(i2.Text));
            list.Add(int.Parse(i3.Text));
            list.Add(int.Parse(i4.Text));
            list.Add(int.Parse(i5.Text));
            Sort(list);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (int t in list)
            {
                sb.Append(t.ToString());
                sb.AppendLine();
            }
            result.Text = sb.ToString();
        }


        private void Sort<T>(List<T> list)
        {
            bool madeChanges;
            int itemCount = list.Count;
            do
            {
                madeChanges = false;
                itemCount--;
                for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
                {
                    int result = Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(list[i], list[i + 1]);

                    if (result > 0)
                    {
                        Swap(list, i, i + 1);
                        madeChanges = true;
                    }
                }
            } while (madeChanges);
        }


        public List<T> Swap<T>(List<T> list,
                int firstIndex,
                int secondIndex)
        {
            T temp = list[firstIndex];
            list[firstIndex] = list[secondIndex];
            list[secondIndex] = temp;

            return list;
        }
```

I wanted that something like this: but gives error
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\users\luis.simbios\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\InterViewPreparation1\InterViewPreparation1\Generics\GenericsSorting1.cs    22  18  InterViewPreparation1

List list = new List();
        list.Add(i1.Text);
        list.Add(i2.Text);
        Sort(list);

Comment: Why, pray tell, aren't you using `List<T>.Sort`?

Comment: +1 to Jason.  Here's the documentation:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx

Comment: because its an interview question in which they asked not to use the sort method.

Comment: How can I change the first lines, so it doesnt use List<int>, If I try to do List<T> it gives compiler errors.

Comment: Related question: [Generics Question Ordering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568022/generics-question-ordering)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> because its an interview question in which they asked not to use the
>   sort method.

In this case you can add a generic constraint [`IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) and then use the `CompareTo()` method:

```
 private void Sort<T>(List<T> list) where T : IComparable<T>
 {
    //...
 }
```

**Edit:**

You would have to write custom code to determine whether the input is string, int or decimal, i.e. use [`TryParse(..)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) - this will be very fragile though. Once you do know the type (one way or another) you can use `MakeGenericType()` and `Activator.CreateInstance()` to create your `List<T>` object at run time and then use `MakeGenericMethod()` to call your generic method:

```
Type type = typeof(string);
IList list = (IList) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type));
//add items to list here

var p = new Program();
MethodInfo method = typeof(Program).GetMethod("Sort");
MethodInfo genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { type });
genericMethod.Invoke(p, new [] {list} );
```

I am pretty sure that is not what the interview question *intended* to ask for.

Comment: I understand that, but my question is how to instantiate the list, so I dont have to define if the content of the list is going to be ints or decimals.  Is this even possible?     List<T> list = new List<T>();
            list.Add(i1.Text);

Comment: @Luis: You want to *detect* what the input type is? You have to know what the type is at least at runtime to use generics here

Comment: yes, that was my idea, I didnt know it was not possible.  But at least the sort method I did was generic.

Comment: @Luis: Updated the answer - I'm pretty sure that's not what the interviewer was shooting for though.

Answer (score 1):

First, as Jason points out, let the platform do the work for you - call .Sort.

Second, it looks to me like you're going to have to select the 'T' of the List based on examining the contents of the textboxes so you can handle ints vs. strings, etc. And then assign items to the list based on that. But once you have decided, your sort won't care.

Comment: please check the edit. its an interview question where they said not to use the sort method, and that the input could be INTS or Decimals.

Comment: @Luis: At the same time? Sorry your question is horribly unclear.

Comment: no my idea is that in the 5 textboxes one user can enter 5 Ints, but another user could enter 5 decimals

Answer (score 1):

You're not going about this the right way. Embrace generics correctly. What you want is this:

```
public string Foo<T>(IEnumerable<string> strings) where T : struct, IComparable<T> {
    var list = strings.Select(s => (T)Convert.ChangeType(s, typeof(T))).ToList();
    list.Sort((x, y) => (x.CompareTo(y)));
    return String.Join("\n", list);
}
```

Now you can say

```
string response = Foo<int>(strings);
```

or

```
string response = Foo<decimal>(strings);
```

depending on which you want.

Note that

1. We use `List<T>.Sort` to do the sorting.
2. We use `String.Join` to build the string to display back to the user.

This should compile, but please excuse trivial errors if it doesn't. I can't fire up the ol' compiler right now.

Edit: I see you edited in that you can't use `List<T>.Sort`. It's easy enough to replace my use of `List<T>.Sort` with your own implementation.

Comment: I understand, but my questions is more regarding how to instantiate a list where yo dont know if the users in the textboxes are going to enter INTS or decimals.

Comment: @Luis: What do you mean? Can the user enter both `int` and `decimal` at the same time?

Comment: no my idea is that in the 5 textboxes one user can enter 5  Ints, but another user could enter 5 decimals.

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought. I solved that problem for you, do you see? If the user enters in the `int` textboxes then you put that input in a seqeuence of strings (call it `strings`) and you invoke `Foo<int>(strings)`. If the user enters in the `decimal` textboxes then you put that input in a sequence of strings (call it `strings`) and you invoke `Foo<decimal>(string)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
private static IList foobar(Type t) 
{ 
  var listType = typeof(List<>); 
  var constructedListType = listType.MakeGenericType(t); 
  var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedListType); 
  return (IList)instance; 
}
```

Then use:

```
IList list = foobar(TYPE);
```

Where `TYPE` is the type that you want you list to be.

Hope this helps!